# Rails Non tabular settings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, settings, application-settings

What is the best practice for storing non-tabular settings (configured by the end-user) for the application?

I know it is possible by creating a model and using it, but creating a one-row-table in the database seems a little wasteful to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the data to YAML, and write it to a configuration file.

```
require "yaml"

File.write(path_to_configuration_file, YAML.dump(obj)) # write

obj = YAML.load_file(path_to_configuration_file) # read
```